# Xamarin.Forms Shell navigation outside the visual hierarchy

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm having a problem with how to implement navigation to pages that are not represented in shell visual hierarchy (defined in my Shell xaml).

From what I read about Shell navigation [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation), there are two ways I can navigate to such a page:

1. Using the Navigation property:

   ```cs
   Navigation.PushAsync(new TargetPage());
   ```
2. Registering a route and using Shell's URI navigation:

   ```cs
   Routing.RegisterRoute("targetPageRoute", typeof(TargetPage));
   ```

   ```cs
   Shell.Current.GoToAsync("targetPageRoute");
   ```

Both methods encounter the same problem: **Once you use either method to navigate to a page outside the visual hierarchy, normal navigation between Shell's flyoutItems (using the flyout menu) will crash the app** with the error:

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'MyProject.TargetPage' was not present in the dictionary.
```

How to reproduce:

1. Add two items to Shell's visual hierarchy:

   ```xml
   <FlyoutItem Title="page 1">
       <Tab>
           <ShellContent>
               <local:Page1 />
           </ShellContent>
       </Tab>
   </FlyoutItem>

   <FlyoutItem Title="page 2">
       <Tab>
           <ShellContent>
               <local:Page2 />
           </ShellContent>
       </Tab>
   </FlyoutItem>
   ```
2. Use a button on Page1 to navigate to Page3 (a page not defined above) using either of the two ways to navigate described at the top of this post:

   ```cs
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3());
   }
   ```
3. Use the flyout menu to navigate to Page2
4. Use the flyout menu to navigate to Page1 - the app should now crash.

I have tested this in my main project and in a small test project extensively and cant seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same issue from xamarin forms' github: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6738
Also, if you scroll down, you'll see pull request, which actually resolves the problem (already helped our company's application).
You have to implement a custom renderer, which is going to inherit from ShellItemRenderer, and override the existing HandleFragmentUpdate (because of the fact, that it uses private fields from the original ShellItemRendererBase, you'll have to rebase them here too (not override, just copy them from current xamarin android ShellItemRendererBase.cs file)).
BUT, as the official docs suggest, you shall not just assign this renderer to a ShellItem derivative, instead, you'll have to create custom ShellRenderer with overriding it's CreateShellItemRenderer method (so it would create your fixed shell item renderer instead of the default one). You just apply this renderer to a custom shell control in xamarin forms.

Of course, everything you do now is temporary, until xamarin pushes new update with this fix included...

Answer (score 1):

you could try to change the shell.xaml like this:

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="page 1">
        <ShellContent  >
            <local:Page1 />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="page 2">
        <ShellContent   >
            <local:Page2 />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Hello, I've tested your suggestion and the app does not crash anymore. However going with this solution means the whole app is contained in a single flyout item, could that be a problem optimization-wise? The app also loses access to bottom tabs, which is a shame.

Comment: what effect do you need ?could you show some sketch？

Comment: if you do't want to show bottom tab,you could set `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"`

Comment: I gave up on trying to navigate outside the shell hierarchy for now, and just added all my pages somewhere in the shell, hiding the tabs. Still, the problem I described seems to be a very serious bug, and your answer is only a work-around without its own problems.

Comment: Should I mark this answer as accepted since it *does* kind of fix the crashing? Can I later mark a different answer in case something better comes up? I'm new here, sorry. :)

Comment: yes，my answer is only a work around，maybe it will be improved in later version

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add your Route before setting the `BindingContext` ?
For Example :

```
public NavigationShell()
{
   Routing.RegisterRoute("targetPageRoute", typeof(TargetPage));
   BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I'm following your solution. The app I'm describing is a simple app with 3 empty pages and a button. Why and what for am I setting the BindingContext?